# prove/disprove: $\log(n)=\Theta(\log(n^{100}-n^{99}))$

Tags: calculus

I have managed to prove that: $$\log(n)=O(\log(n^{100}-n^{99}))$$
But I'm wondering if it is true to state that:
$$\log(n)=\Theta(\log(n^{100}-n^{99}))$$
In other words, I'm trying to prove that $$\log(n)=\Omega(\log(n^{100}-n^{99}))$$
But I can't seem to figure out to to prove it. Is it true? if so, what is the way to prove it?

Comment: **HINT:** $\log(ab^k) = \log(a)+\log(b^k) = \log(a)+k\log(b)$

Answer (score 1):

See the following:
$$A = \log(n^{100}-n^{99}) = \log(n^{99}(n-1)) = \log(n^{99}) + \log(n-1) =$$
$$99\log(n) + \log(n-1)$$

$$\Rightarrow 99\log(n) < A < 100\log(n), \text{for } n > 2$$

Hence, $A = \Theta(\log(n))$. Therefore, we can say $\log(n) = \Theta(A)$ because of the property of $\Theta$.